# Cant hold css change state with if statement

Tags: jquery

---updated fiddle still not functioning  www.jsfiddle.net/atZPn/5 Trying to get the text in the input box to stay dark only if data has been entered.

http://jsfiddle.net/atZPn/5/

code:

```
   $(".searchbox").blur(function() {
    var searchbox = this,
        searchbox_val = $.trim( this.value );
    if (searchbox_val.length > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $(searchbox).addClass("blur");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Why use jQuery if you're going to use document.getElementByClassName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementByClassName` should `getElementsByClassName` and `searchbox_val` should `searchbox_val[0]`.

```
/* Search Box Leave */
$(".searchbox").blur(function() {
    var searchbox_val = document.getElementsByClassName("searchbox");
    if (searchbox_val[0].value.length > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass("blur");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Yon can try also like following:

```
$(".searchbox").blur(function() {
    var searchbox = $(this),
        searchbox_val = $.trim( searchbox.val() );
    if (searchbox_val.length > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        searchbox.addClass("blur");
        return false;
    }
});
```

#### [Updated]

***HTML***

```
<input class="searchbox" type="text" placeholder="Just some text" />
```

***jQuery***

```
$(".searchbox").blur(function() {
    var searchbox = this,
        searchbox_val = $.trim( this.value );
    if (searchbox_val.length > 0) {
        $(searchbox).addClass("blur");
        return true;
    } else {
        $(searchbox).removeClass("blur");
        return false;
    }
});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/atZPn/8/)***

Comment: was just replying to my post, just saw the [0] and missed the s! getting there sry silly question

Comment: No need for this `getElementsByClassName` to get `this`.

Comment: because searchbox is already the class subbject for the function? updated the fiddle but still doesnt hold? http://jsfiddle.net/atZPn/5

Comment: this isnt a node so doesnt require [0]?

Comment: @david do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/atZPn/8/..check new demo

Comment: Thank you, good post in the end just finished half a days work perfectly working! thanks everyone